# Sql single column to multiple on '.' delemiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with data as `abc.123`, `def.345` and so on. It is basically a name followed by a `.` and then a code. I am able to divide them using

```
select 
LEFT(Campaign, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.', Campaign + ' ') -1, -1), LEN(Campaign))),
STUFF(Campaign, 1, Len(Campaign) +1- CHARINDEX('.',Reverse(Campaign)), '')
 from myTable;
```

Input set:

```
| myColumn |
| abc.123  |
| def.345  | 
|  444     |
```

However, for data like '444' it shows:

```
|Name| Code |
|abc | 123  |
|def | 345  | 
|444 |      |    (SHOULD BE => |   |  444 |)
```

Assumptions:
Data can be without a '.' In such case we can insert the data in either Name or Code depending on datatype ie  Name=>Alphanumeric, Code=>Numeric.
eg: Data like

```
999 =>     |     | 999 |
a24.345 => | a24 | 345 |
a72     => | a72 |     |
```

Comment: Is abc.123, def.345 one or two values? (I.e. is it "abc.123, def.345", or "abc.123" and "def.345"?)

Comment: I am using Sql Server. And abc.123 is one value. i have updated the question with input set

Comment: What happens if the data is like `abc`, with no dot or `123` after it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: the param before . would be alphanumeric but after the . will always be numeric.

Comment: you could use two regex pattern in your select. `.[0-9]+` to display the name without the code and `[A-Za-z].` to display the code without the name.

Comment: @user1908559 What if there is no dot? Is it guaranteed to be `code` then?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: we can only guarantee its a code if is numeric.

Comment: Update your question with a list of assumptions please

Comment: @JoePhilllips: I have added the assumptions and the expected input output. Hope that adds more clearity.

Comment: Just one more proof that concatenated values are evil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CASE expressions together with the LIKE operand in order to differentiate the cases:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN Campaign LIKE '[a-z]%' THEN LEFT(Campaign, CHARINDEX('.', Campaign + '.') - 1)
    ELSE null
    END AS Name, 

    CASE
    WHEN Campaign LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN Campaign
    WHEN Campaign LIKE '%.[0-9]%' THEN
        RIGHT(Campaign,  LEN(Campaign) - CHARINDEX('.', Campaign))
    ELSE null
    END AS Code
FROM myTable
```

You can see an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae7ef7/1

Comment: THANK YOU! This is just perfect. It worked for all the three cases :) thank you

Comment: It works for even more cases: it work for `null` columns, for campaigns starting with a `'.'`, ending with a `'.'` or containing just a  `'.'`. (7 cases alltogether).

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that. I really appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when myColumn like '%.%'
             then <your code here>
             else myColumn
        end) as code
```

Comment: I am trying but i am bad at writing sql. Not sure how to transform this code to work for my assumptions.